# Openlayers 3 ol.layer.Tile shift from version 3.6.0 and forward

Tags: openlayers, tiles

I have local tiles on my OL 3 app using version 3.6.0.
I've noticed when I upgrade to version 3.7.0 I need to rewrite my tileUrlFunction or else they don't shown anymore.

This is the code change I need to do :

```
 source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    tileUrlFunction: function (coordinate) {
        if (coordinate == null) {
            return "";
        }
        var z = coordinate[0];
        var x = coordinate[1];
        //var y = coordinate[2]; //3.6.0
        var y = -coordinate[2]; //3.7.0

        return 'tiles/controlroom/' + z + '/' + x + '/' + y + '.png';
    },
    minZoom: 7,
    maxZoom: 16
})
```

Once I change to 3.7.0 there is big deviation the further my **zoom out is**

Example Max Zoom Out:

[image]

When I zoom In , the gap seems to get closer where it used to be with 3.6.0

[image]

Why does this happens ?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a change of how OpenLayers handles some tile coordinates, as noted in the [release notes for OpenLayers 3.7](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.7.0). I have written more about the issue in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454234/using-bing-maps-quadkeys-as-openlayers-3-tile-source/32614039#32614039

You are not far from solving your issue, you just have to shift the y coordinate one step down:

```
// notice the "- 1" part 
var y = -coordinate[2] - 1; //3.7.0
```